# Android - Content disappearing after orientation change

Tags: android, android-orientation

My `SectionsPageAdapter` looks like this:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<PopularFragment> fragments;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        fragments = new ArrayList<MainActivity.PopularFragment>();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).
        PopularFragment f = PopularFragment.newInstance(position);
        fragments.add(f);

        return f;
    }

    public List<PopularFragment> getFragments() {
        return fragments;
    }
(...)
```

In my `Activity`'s `onCreate` I call:

```
new DownloadTask(new Handler()) {
    private boolean result;

    @Override
    void doOnUiThread() {
        if (!result) {
            MainActivity.noConnection(MainActivity.this);
            return;
        }

        for (PopularFragment f : mSectionsPagerAdapter.getFragments())
            f.load();

        loaded = true;
    }

    @Override
    void doInBackground() {
        result = popular.download();
    }
}.execute();
```

After orientation change `load()` is never called. Why is that?

Here is whole `MainActivity.java`: http://pastebin.com/0pEDdjHS

Answer (score 1):

probably it's simply because the doOnUiThread is called before the getItem in the adapter.
Check for mSectionsPagerAdapter.getFragments() it'll probably be empty

Comment: You're right, but how can I wait for fragments to be created? Also in fragment's `onCreateView` I have `if (((MainActivity) getActivity()).isLoaded()) load();` yet it is not called...

Comment: How about moving the new DownloadTask() code in onStart() ?

Comment: That still would not probably guarantee you that the fragments have been created. The code is a bit broken. Probably you should simply call the activity from the fragment.